# x and y axis labels not present in ctree

Tags: r, party

I am trying to redo an earlier ctree project I did this summer. When I go to plot the results, I use code like this:

```
fit<- ctree(Y~., data=df, control=ctree.control(minbucket=20))
```

This runs, then I go to plot it using this code:

```
plot(fit, labels=TRUE, terminal_panel=node_barplot(fit, beside=TRUE,col="black", fill=c("coral4", "chartreuse4")))
```

However, I do not get labels on either the y axis or the levels of my dependent variable Y showing up in the terminal node barplots. Y has two levels, "Yes" or "No"

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I have put a link to a fake dataset here:
[DATA FROM GITHUB](https://github.com/ngfrey/StackOverflowQ)

Here is a picture showing my result, note how there are no x or y axis labels on the terminal nodes. I'm not sure why this is happening. 
[image]

Comment: Could you show us a bit of `df` with `dput(df)`?

Comment: sure. Give me 20 minutes...I'm removing and re-installing R, RStudio, and all my packages at the moment

Comment: I have put a link to a fake csv file with the real column names up on gitHub...you can find it here:

https://github.com/ngfrey/StackOverflowQ

Comment: So you're using `ctree()` from the `party` package? Just want to be sure.

Comment: I am. I only load the partykit package when I start my R session. Also, removing and re-installing R/RStudio did nothing for me.  I have no idea why I was getting good plots earlier this summer, but now bad plots.  I haven't touched the code or the data.

Comment: Are you sure the csv you provided is correct? There's no `Y` to reference in `ctree()`.

Comment: I was just using Y as a general reference. I updated my gitHub with a better fake data set that will actually split, and included my code in the cTreeExample.r file. If I can, I'll post a picture of my results to illustrate the problem. --NF

Comment: `detach` the `partykit` package and try again. Use either one of them but not both.

Comment: Wow.  It worked.  I NEVER even loaded the `party` package, just `partykit`...If I used just the party package, things worked.  I don't know if I'm more embarrassed or relieved. Either way, I'd like to thank both CephBirk and David Arenburg for their help.

Answer (score 1):

Restarted R, only loaded the `party` package. Works well. Good advice all. Thx for the help.

Best, 
NF